# Como habilitar ou mostrar um botão em php, após um cadastro?

Tags: php, button

Queria saber como faço para habilitar, ou até mesmo mostrar um botão após fazer um cadastro.
Ou seja, eu tenho um formulário, e após o preenchimento dele e o envio das informações, eu quero mostrar um outro botão.

```html
<form method="post" action="../controller/controllerEmbarcacao.php">

  <!-- BOTÕES DE INPUTS -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" autofocus="" required="" name="nome" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="capacidade"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Capacidade: </label>
    <input type="text" id="capacidade" autofocus="" required="" name="capacidade" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cidadePartida"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Cidade Partida: </label>
    <?php 
       
         $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
         echo "<select class='form-control' name='cidadePartida' id='cidadePartida'>";
         while($x = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
          echo "";
          echo "<option value=";
          echo $x['CID_CODIGO'];
          echo "> ".$x['CID_NOME']." </option>";
         };
         echo "</select>";

       ?>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cidadeChegada"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Cidade Chegada: </label>
    <?php 
       
         $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
         echo "<select class='form-control' name='cidadeChegada' id='cidadeChegada'>";
         while($x = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
          echo "";
          echo "<option value=";
          echo $x['CID_CODIGO'];
          echo "> ".$x['CID_NOME']." </option>";
         };
         echo "</select>";

       ?>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="diaViagem"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Dia da Viagem: </label>
    <input type="date" name="diaViagem" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="horaViagem"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Hora da Viagem: </label>
    <input type="time" name="horaViagem" class="form-control">
  </div>




  <?php
    /*
     if($success == 1){
      echo '<label>O valor da sua encomenda é: R$ '.ceil($tempo).'</label>';
      }
                 */
    ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-format" id="btn-cadastro">Cadastrar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved" ></span></button>

    <input type="hidden" name="opcao" value="1">

</form>
```

Comment: Onde exatamente quer mostrar esse botão? O formulário é enviado para outra página com target default  que é (_self). Se o formulário for enviado para a mesma página ai dá para mostrar um botão após submetê-lo.

Comment: o formulario é enviado para a pagina de controller, eu gostaria que assim, que eu fizesse a ação de clicar no botão, pra enviar o formulario, ele me mostrasse o botão

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
 if (!empty($_POST))
 {
    $novoBotao="<button .........>......</button>";
 }
```

No local que você quer que ele apareça

```
 <?php echo $novoBotao ?>
```

Comment: apareceu esse erro na minha tela

Notice: Undefined variable: novo in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC - Programa 3\view\cadastrarEmbarcacao.php on line 167

Comment: isso ocorre quando se tenta usar uma variável não declarada (ou definida, no caso do PHP). A solução não poderia ser outra: criar a variável antes de usá-la.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['btnCadastrar'])){
    ?>


    <script>
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
      $('#opcao').removeClass('hidden');
    });


    </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="../controller/controllerEmbarcacao.php">

  <!-- BOTÕES DE INPUTS -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" autofocus="" required="" name="nome" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="capacidade"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Capacidade: </label>
    <input type="text" id="capacidade" autofocus="" required="" name="capacidade" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cidadePartida"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Cidade Partida: </label>
    <?php 
       
         $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
         echo "<select class='form-control' name='cidadePartida' id='cidadePartida'>";
         while($x = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
          echo "";
          echo "<option value=";
          echo $x['CID_CODIGO'];
          echo "> ".$x['CID_NOME']." </option>";
         };
         echo "</select>";

       ?>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cidadeChegada"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Cidade Chegada: </label>
    <?php 
       
         $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
         echo "<select class='form-control' name='cidadeChegada' id='cidadeChegada'>";
         while($x = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
          echo "";
          echo "<option value=";
          echo $x['CID_CODIGO'];
          echo "> ".$x['CID_NOME']." </option>";
         };
         echo "</select>";

       ?>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="diaViagem"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Dia da Viagem: </label>
    <input type="date" name="diaViagem" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="horaViagem"><span class="vermelho">*</span> Hora da Viagem: </label>
    <input type="time" name="horaViagem" class="form-control">
  </div>




  <?php
    /*
     if($success == 1){
      echo '<label>O valor da sua encomenda é: R$ '.ceil($tempo).'</label>';
      }
                 */
    ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-format" id="btn-cadastro" name="btnCadastrar">Cadastrar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved" ></span></button>

    <input type="hidden" name="opcao" id="opcao" value="1">

</form>
```